# SSH into another mac on different network using port other than 22

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

I tried to access one of my mac on a different network using a specified port: 1234

```
ssh remoteuser@remoteip -p 1234
```

but I got the result that `connection refused`. How do I specify the port I want to use other than the default 22?

Comment: Try adding `-v` to the command line; this may help debugging

Comment: ```debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 1234.
debug1: connect to address ip port 1234: Connection refused```

Comment: Then the server is not running on that port, or blocked by a firewall.

Comment: how do I get around with it?

Comment: @JackeyOL Without more info about your setup, it's impossible to tell. Is the remote Mac actually running an ssh server on port #1234? What firewalls lie between the client and that Mac? Is the remote Mac on a private network, and if so what IP are you using for it and is port mapping set up on the router for that private network?

Comment: How did you tell your other Mac to run its `ssh` server on port 1234?

Comment: I set it on the router website, designating port 1234 for the remote mac

Comment: If there is a router involved, are you sure the connection to the other Mac is actually made or you are already stuck at the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comment exchange,

> How did you tell your other Mac to run its ssh server on port 1234?
> – pion Feb 19 at 23:19

> I set it on the router website, designating port 1234 for the remote Mac
> – JackeyOL Feb 20 at 5:25

it sounds like you did not actually configure `sshd` on your remote Mac to listen on port `1234` rather than its default port `22`. This is why you're getting a refused connection: Although you may be *routing* traffic correctly to your remote Mac, `sshd` did not *open* port `1234` on that Mac in the first place.

You can confirm this by getting onto your remote Mac and either running a port scan (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Network Utility.app`, *Port Scan*, address `127.0.0.1`, ports `1234-1234`) or by trying to `ssh` locally (`ssh -p 1234 user@localhost`).

**To fix this:** You can change your `sshd` port by **[editing its `launchd` property list](https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x)**. Note that you will first need to disable System Integrity Protection on macOS 10.11+ and remount your System volume as read/write on macOS 10.15+.

Comment: Your answer is brilliant! I scanned my ports and 1234 is not open but 22 is still open and I think that's the reason. I enabled the port 1234 in `/etc/sshd_config` as many suggested online, but it won't working. Not sure if that's not a osx thing or just simply deprecated.

Comment: @JackeyOL It's deprecated. The link I gave above will show you how to edit the `sshd` launchd plist to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the destination/address is passed to the target computer as a command. Try

```
ssh -p 1234 user@remote
```

instead.

Comment: No luck. Got exactly same result: `Connection refused`